# Not able to pass multi values from prompts to Bi Publisher 11g

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

I am using a choice list in dashboard prompt with default value:"All Column values" and set to a presentation  variable:"presvar

In BIP 11G data model,in where clause i am writing it as:

where(tablename.colname in (:presvar))

This is working only when i select single value in prompt ,if i select multi values in dashboard prompt it is not fetching me exact results.

Kindly help if someone has faced the situation

Version:11.1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for single values, multiple values, and a null value:

```
WHERE (tablename.colname IN (:presvar) OR 'DUMMY' IN (:presvar || 'DUMMY'))
```